# Does the noun "parley" always imply "negotiation between opposing groups"?

Tags: word-usage

I read a daily newspaper issued by "The Hindu". It includes a special segment called "Parley" in which there is any discussion about various notable topics.

Now as you might know the word "parley" means negotiation of terms between opposing groups. So I wanted to ask, does "parley" has to "happen between opposing groups" or it could refer to any sort of discussion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The noun *parley* is still used by some people today in normal conversation. It doesn't have to imply that the people are enemies; it doesn't even have to imply that there is conflict. As you say, it *can* be used to simply say that people are having a discussion.

From [Merriam-Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parley) definition of the noun:

> **1 a** : a conference for discussion of points in dispute
>   **1 b** : a conference with an enemy
>   **2** : DISCUSSION
>
> //  held a *parley* to debate the proposed change in the town's zoning laws
>   //  North Korea is also threatening to scrap the Singapore *parley* unless denuclearization is taken off the agenda.
>   — Nicholas Eberstadt, WSJ, "With Kim Jong Un, There’s No ‘Win-Win’," 23 May 2018

And examples from the equivalent verb form:

> //  in an effort to win the goodwill of the locals, the developers *parleyed* with them before finalizing plans for the massive mall
>   // Those categories are for individuals who do not seek to join the U.S., but rather represent nations seeking to *parley* with—or conquer—it.

Answer (score 0):

A "parley" is not a common term, it is probably only known to most speakers in the context of the "Pirates of the Carribean" film.  It has an old-fashioned, quirky, slightly comical nuance, rather like the pirates in the film.

You wouldn't say "I'm going to a parley with my collegues", unless you were making a joke (the "joke" is that my colleages are flamboyant pirates).  But as a title of a newspaper column it is fine. Titles are not meant to be normal English; they can be quirky, and a bit funny.

The dictionary definition could be: 1 (dated) a negotiation between adversaries.  2 (jocular) any meeting for discussion.